# I have Expo Snack project 'cmsApp'. how to export project as 'application' and run it in My Android Phone

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

#### When I made apk using `EAS build` then it doing crash... how to export apk successfully from expo snack project.

*what i am doing to make application:*

Step1 - download zip file from expo using Download button which placed on Top-Right Corner.

Step2 - `npm i`

Step3 - `npm i -g expo-cli`

Step4 - `eas build -p android --profile preview`

Now, Command Prompt give me link to download application as apk.

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

but, when i install it in my phone, then it is crash.... how to export apk successfully from expo snack without crashing.

**when I debug project then it gives me an error:**

```
caught SyntaxError D:\ProgramFiles\myAppExpo\myfirstapp\node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js:1
import registerRootComponent from 'expo/build/launch/registerRootComponent';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1187:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1231:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1321:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1125:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:965:12)
    at executeUserEntryPoint (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
    at <anonymous> (internal/main/run_main_module:23:47)
```

*AppEntry.js:*

```
const registerRootComponent = require('expo/builad/launch/registerRootComponent').default;

import App from '../../App';

registerRootComponent(App);
```

I want to make Build, download and install apk in my android phone and I want to publish it in Play Store.